# Trying to understanding the functionality of createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I have written a small program to understand the functionality of the above function actually. 
Description of the function says the following, Creates a Statement object that will generate ResultSet objects with the given type and concurrency. To test this I have written a small program which displays the contents of a table in database. and then I display it repeatedly, after sometime delay. Meanwhile I modify/or change the contents in the Database. I was actually expecting that to be displayed on the output screen. but nothing like that happened.

Can some one give me a hint regarding this. below is the code snipped and the output..

```
String sql= "select * from customer";
  st=con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);

    rs=st.executeQuery(sql);

    for(int j=1;j<21;j++){
        System.out.println("Count is "+j);

    while(rs.next()){
        System.out.println(rs.getInt(1)+"\t"+rs.getString(2)+"\t"+rs.getString(3)+"\t"+rs.getInt(4)+"\t"+rs.getInt(5));
        for(int i=0;i<1000000000l;i++);
    }

    while(rs.previous()){
        System.out.println(rs.getInt(1)+"\t"+rs.getString(2)+"\t"+rs.getString(3)+"\t"+rs.getInt(4)+"\t"+rs.getInt(5));
        for(int i=0;i<1000000000l;i++);
    }

    }
```

### output

Count is 1

101 cust1   cust1@gmail.com 1111    1000

102 cust2   cust2@gmail.com 2222    2000

103 cust3   cust3@gmail.com 3333    3000

104 cust4   cust4@gmail.com 4444    4000

105 cust5   cust5@gmail.com 5555    5000

106 cust6   cust6@gmail.com 6666    6000

107 cust7   cust7@gmail.com 7777    7000

108 cust8   cust8@gmail.com 8888    8000

109 cust9   cust9@gmail.com 9999    9000

110 cust10  cust10@gmail.com    1010    10000

111 cust11  cust11@gmail.com    1011    11000

111 cust11  cust11@gmail.com    1011    11000

110 cust10  cust10@gmail.com    1010    10000

109 cust9   cust9@gmail.com 9999    9000

108 cust8   cust8@gmail.com 8888    8000

107 cust7   cust7@gmail.com 7777    7000

106 cust6   cust6@gmail.com 6666    6000

105 cust5   cust5@gmail.com 5555    5000

104 cust4   cust4@gmail.com 4444    4000

103 cust3   cust3@gmail.com 3333    3000

102 cust2   cust2@gmail.com 2222    2000

101 cust1   cust1@gmail.com 1111    1000

Count is 2

101 cust1   cust1@gmail.com 1111    1000

102 cust2   cust2@gmail.com 2222    2000

103 cust3   cust3@gmail.com 3333    3000

104 cust4   cust4@gmail.com 4444    4000

105 cust5   cust5@gmail.com 5555    5000

106 cust6   cust6@gmail.com 6666    6000

107 cust7   cust7@gmail.com 7777    7000

108 cust8   cust8@gmail.com 8888    8000

109 cust9   cust9@gmail.com 9999    9000

110 cust10  cust10@gmail.com    1010    10000

111 cust11  cust11@gmail.com    1011    11000

111 cust11  cust11@gmail.com    1011    11000

110 cust10  cust10@gmail.com    1010    10000

109 cust9   cust9@gmail.com 9999    9000

108 cust8   cust8@gmail.com 8888    8000

107 cust7   cust7@gmail.com 7777    7000

106 cust6   cust6@gmail.com 6666    6000

105 cust5   cust5@gmail.com 5555    5000

104 cust4   cust4@gmail.com 4444    4000

103 cust3   cust3@gmail.com 3333    3000

102 cust2   cust2@gmail.com 2222    2000

101 cust1   cust1@gmail.com 1111    1000

**Note:I changed the database content before the before it  completed printing of first set of values i.e (count->1)**

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the key point lies in `ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE`'s JavaDoc:

*"[...] a ResultSet object that is scrollable and **generally** sensitive to changes to the data that underlies the ResultSet."*

Maybe *"generally"* is rather meant to be *usually* here, not *universally*. In the sense of being a CAN, not a MUST. But with high probability that it's implemented. (But maybe that's just because I'm not a native English speaker :-)

What if you insert/delete records? Did you try it with different DBs?

Comment: Yes, you do have a point, anyways I shall do some trials and then get back to you. I shall keep you updated give me some days time. 

As far as your language is concerned. Its very clear. :)

Comment: In [The Java™ Tutorials, Retrieving and Modifying Values from Result Sets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html) on the other hand: _"The result set reflects changes made to the underlying data source while the result set remains open."_. Do you perform a COMMIT after modifying/changing?

Answer (score 0):

The field `ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE` creates a `ResultSet` object whose cursor can move both forward and backward relative to the current position and to an absolute position.

The field `ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE` creates a `ResultSet` object that can be updated while `CONCUR_READ_ONLY` creates a `ResultSet` that cannot be updated but only it can be read.

**The problem that you cannot see any changes that you made in the database table is because you are using read only type ResultSet.**

Comment: Thank you Muhammad, I understand that.but my issue is when the value is modified that is not getting updated, even though I am using  ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE.  Mr Gerold Brose, has suggested me few tips, I shall try those on a later date. If I find any positive result I shall keep you updated.